# Java Card and Sim Toolkit applet

Tags: java, eclipse

I have couple of question about javacard and Sim Toolkit applet. 
1- What is difference between javacard and Sim Toolkit applet ? 
2- I can write a simple javacard applet in Eclipse with JCOP , But how can i write Sim Toolkit  applet in there? 
3- When i want to add Sim.Jar Library in javacard Project , Eclipse just throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

**Javacard applet vs SIM toolkit applet** 
The SIM toolkit applet is also Javacard applet. However, it uses the APIs from `sim.toolkit` and `sim.access` according to 3GPP TS 43.019 or related specs. Instead of using `process()` as the main entry, the SIM toolkit main entry is `processToolkit()`.

**Write SIM Toolkit applet in JCOP** 
You can write it using JCOP or plain Eclipse by adding the required JARs/libraries.

**Exception on SIM.JAR library** 
Please post your configuration and the exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the main difference is that :

SIMToolKit applet react to events (selection menu, reaction reception of SMS etc ...) so more powerful, please take at look at this [thesis](http://miun.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:423013/FULLTEXT02.pdf)  its a good overview, the best that i seen in the web.

you can also look a this guide start if you are using net beans.

Comment: I found a better explanation in this thread 
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325663/send-apdu-commands-to-usim-sim-card-in-android)